# Cannot find any module that is part of a package

Tags: angular

I am unable to find any module that is part of any npm install

for example, on my app.component.ts

```
//Caannot find module
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {NbButtonModule, NbLayoutModule, NbSidebarModule, NbThemeModule} from "@nebular/theme";
import {RouterModule} from '@angular/router';
//nx library
import {TestModule} from "@mvt-front-end/test";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
```

in my direction I have the json files that may help - packages.json, tsconfig.json, tsconfig.base.json, angular.json, nx.json

[image: As you can see here]

Comment: Did you create an angular app through ng new <name> and have you run npm install on the command line?

Comment: Run `npm install` in your project folder.